# Matching the absence of events

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I have a simple stream of status of objects :

```
define stream statusStream (id string, success bool);
```

I want to query all  of objects which are "failed" (success=false) since 5 minutes : all event of statusStream (, false) where there are no event (same id, true) within 5 minutes.

What is the simplest siddhi query for this kind of job ?

Currently I have :

```
define stream statusStream (id string, success bool);

from statusStream[ success == false ]#window.time(5 minutes)
insert expired events into expiredStatusStream;

from every status = statusStream[ success == false ]
  -> ackStatus = statusStream[ success == true and id == status.id]
    or expiredStatus = expiredStatusStream[ id == status.id ]
select status.id, ackStatus.id as ackId
into filteredStatusStream;

from filteredStatusStream[ ackStatus.id is null ]
insert into failedStatusStream;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are getting 'success == false' messages to indicate failure, then try below execution plan:

```
@Import('statusStream:1.0.0')
define stream statusStream (id string, success bool);

@Export('alertStream:1.0.0')
define stream alertStream (alert string);

from statusStream
select id, success, time:timestampInMilliseconds() as ts
insert into statusStreamWithTS;

from every e1=statusStreamWithTS[success==false], statusStreamWithTS[success==false]*, e2=statusStreamWithTS[success==false AND (e2.ts - e1.ts) >= 500000]
select 'some message' as alert
insert into alertStream;
```

Here, an alert will be generated if we continue to get 'success==false' messages for 5 mins.